# Can not use GET and POST function to AWS API gateway with HTTP proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have set up an API on AWS API gateway with HTTP proxy 
https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev

This API is in front of the public DNS of ALB:
http://xxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

ALB direct the traffic to different microservices (ms1, ms2, dummy), where ms1 and ms2 will take POST method to /ms1 and /ms2, and dummy one will take any other request (means GET and POST to any /* other than /ms1 and /ms2) to return some default response.

When I test the API in API gateway, it works fine. But when I do it in postman, I can do the POST to ms1 and ms2 from https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ms1 and https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ms2, but can not do https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev via GET and POST (this works at the testing in API gateway). The error message is:

```
{
    "message": "No method found matching route / for http method GET."
}
```

I set up the AWS authentication in POSTMAN, so it should not be an issue. I guess I may miss some things in the header. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sanity check : have you deployed your latest api changes ? Possible reason why "Test" in api gateway works but not when using postman. Another debugging approach will be to first tech by hitting ALB directly if it is handling any path resolution to dummy service correctly.

Comment: @Vishal The API deploy is up to date and directly hitting ALB can provide the right response. I'm using python right now. In the dummy service, I just ask the server to return the follow: 

@app.route('/')
def dummy():
   return "What do you want me to do?"